# Compiler doesn't complain about wrong syntax

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

So I have this brilliant line of code that I happened to have a typo on:

```
for(int x=firstKey; x <- runner->numKeys; x++){...}
```

Not only did the program compiled without a hitch but also linked and ran without a problem.

Of course the for loop didn't run even once. But I can't understand what `<-` is being interpreted as? How is this legal?

Comment: That's the unary minus operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's being interpreted this way:

```
for(int x = firstKey; x < -runner->numKeys; x++)
```

Whitespace is mostly insignificant in C.  Exceptions include that you cannot add spaces inside tokens like `<=` or `::`.  But spaces between tokens are generally allowed, and removing spaces between tokens is also allowed most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's *not* wrong syntax, it's perfectly *valid* syntax, as are the statements:

```
if (a = 7) doSomething(); // will set a to 7 and call doSomething().
b == 42;                  // won't set b to 42 at all.
```

What you have is a semantic issue rather than a syntactic one. The *meaning,* rather than the construction, is incorrect.

The expression:

```
x <- runner->numKeys
```

is interpreted as:

```
x < (-runner->numKeys)
```

In other words, the loop will run for as long as `x` is less than the negation of the number of keys. Since the number of keys will most likely be positive (though there is an edge case of zero to consider), the negation will be negative, hence the body will never be run if the first key is non-negative.

In any event, the edge cases are irrelevant since the behaviour will still be incorrect, just in a different way. I'm gathering what you *probably* meant was one of:

```
x <= runner->numKeys
x <  runner->numKeys
```